# Tax Zone using fixed quantity

Tags: magento2, tax, taxes, adobe-commerce

I am learning Magento and I Want to add a tax for specific country or state.

I know that Magento already has a feature to add % rate tax by zone
[https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/tax/tax-zones-rates.html#:~:text=On%20the%20Admin%20sidebar%2C%20go,code%20for%20Zip%2FPost%20Code](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/tax/tax-zones-rates.html#:%7E:text=On%20the%20Admin%20sidebar%2C%20go,code%20for%20Zip%2FPost%20Code).

The module works by a percent but I wan a fixed price to add. Someone knows how can i do that?